# TypeError when writing my own evaluation_metric for xgboost in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, xgboost

I want to create my own f_score evaluation metric when using xgboost classifier for binary classification.

My metric is

```
def f_score(preds,y):
   df = pd.DataFrame({'predict':pred, 'true':y.get_labels()})
   correct_1 = len(df.loc[(df['predict'] == 1) & (df['true'] == 1])
   wrong_1 = len(df.loc[(df['predict'] == 0]) & (df['true'] == 0])
   wrong_0 = len(df.loc[(df['predict'] == 0]) & (df['true'] == 1])
   precission = correct_1 / (correct_1+wrong_1)
   recall = correct_1/(correct_1+wrong_0)
   score = 2*precission*recall/(precission+recall)
   return score
```

Then I have

```
    cv_results = xgboost.cv(
                 params,
                 dtrain,
                 num_boost_round = 999,
                 seed = 42,
                 nfold = 5,
                 feval = f_score,
                 early_stopping_rounds = 10
                 )
```

When I run the code it performs one iteration of my constructed metric and then after returning "score" it throws a "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object"

And I can't figure out why this is happening. Any idea how to solve it?

```
  File "c:\Users\esilkas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python- 
2019.2.5433\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 357, in main
    run()
 File "c:\Users\esilkas\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python- 
2019.2.5433\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 257, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File 
"C:\Users\esilkas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 
263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File 
"C:\Users\esilkas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 
96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File 
"C:\Users\esilkas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 
85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File 
"c:\Users\esilkas\Documents\apps\masterthesis\Model\xgb_tuning_outlier.py", 
line 293, in <module>
    feval = f_score,
  File "C:\Users\esilkas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\xgboost\training.py", line 446, in cv
    res = aggcv([f.eval(i, feval) for f in cvfolds])
  File "C:\Users\esilkas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\xgboost\training.py", line 446, in <listcomp>
    res = aggcv([f.eval(i, feval) for f in cvfolds])
  File "C:\Users\esilkas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\xgboost\training.py", line 234, in eval
    return self.bst.eval_set(self.watchlist, iteration, feval)
  File "C:\Users\esilkas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\xgboost\core.py", line 1115, in eval_set
    name, val = feval_ret
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: I added the traceback now.

Comment: It looks like a function is expected to return a 2-tuple and actually returns an integer. The name `feval_ret` could imply it is your `f_score`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I didn't notice that you need to return 2 arguments. I need to return ("f_score", f_score)

Comment: Please look at https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/guide-python/custom_objective.py